# Usuário digita 15 números aleatórios, programa retorna a média, os números maiores que a média e os menores que a média!

Tags: python, lista

```
num = []
soma = 0
media = 0
for i in range(1, 16):
    num = int(input('Digite um número: '))
    soma += num
    media = soma / 15
    if num[i] > media:
        print('Maires que a media {}'.format(num[i]))
    if num[i] < media:
        print('Menores que a media {}'.format(num[i]))
print('Soma {} e Media {}'.format(soma, media))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Problema

Olá Uberlan, pelo que entendi você gostaria de um script simples para calcular alguns valores referentes aos números digitados aleatoriamente.

Sendo mostrado: a `soma`, `média`, `valores abaixo da média`, `valores acima da média`.

Da maneira que está fazendo, não é funcional pois a verificação dos números `acima/abaixo` da média está sendo verificado na inserção dos valores, sendo assim sem saber qual é necessariamente a média, você primeiro tem que incluir os valores para poder fazer as verificações desejadas.

## Solução

Como resolução, fiz o seguinte código que atende o que está querendo fazer.

```
# criando o array para a inclusão dos 15 números aleatórios
numbers = []

# array para separaçnao dos números maiores e menores que a média
above_average_numbers = []
below_average_numbers = []

# laço de repetição para executar o código identado 15 vezes
for i in range(15):
    numbers.append(int(input('Digite o {}º número: '.format(i+1))))

# realizando a soma dos números digitados
sum_numbers = sum(numbers)

# calculando a média
average = sum_numbers / len(numbers)

# laco de repetição para facilitar a manipulação dos números abaixo da média, e acima da média
for number in numbers:
    if number >= average:
        above_average_numbers.append(number)
    else:

        below_average_numbers.append(number)

# retornos
print('\n* A soma dos valores do vetor {} totaliza o valor de {}!\n* A média dos valores é: {}\n* Temos {} números abaixo da média: {}\n* E temos {} números acima da média: {}'.format(numbers, sum_numbers, average, len(below_average_numbers), below_average_numbers, len(above_average_numbers), above_average_numbers))
```

Algumas informações do código: fiz a criação de 3 `vetores` para armazenar os valores:

- `numbers` para receber todos os valores que forem digitados, incluindo utilizando o método `append()` - que inclui o elemento no final da estrutura.
- `above_average_numbers` para receber os valores acima ou iguais a média
- `below_average_numbers` para os valores abaixo da média

No laço de repetição de inclusão:

```
for i in range(15):
    numbers.append(int(input('Digite o {}º número: '.format(i+1))))
```

Fui adicionando os valores solicitados no `array` de maneira padronizada para `integer` inteiro, porém, poderá alterar caso tenha necessidade, e também mostrei a ordem dos números pelo `i+1` pois na primeira iteração o `i` possui o valor de `0`.

- `sum_numbers = sum(numbers)` está realizando a soma de todos os valores do `array`. Pois `sum()` é uma função nativa do `Python`, então, porque não utiliza-la?
- `average = sum_numbers / len(numbers)` calcula a média com os valores obtidos pela `soma`que realizamos anteriormente, junto com o tamanho do vetor que incluímos todos os valores. `len()` é uma função que retorna para nós o tamanho do vetor.

Realizamos posteriormente outro laço de repetição para separar os valores:

```
for number in numbers:
    if number >= average:
        above_average_numbers.append(number)
    else:

        below_average_numbers.append(number)
```

Acredito que esta parte está facil de compreender, utilizamos a variável local `number`para obter o valor respectivo de `numbers` - isso é um padrão de programação apresentado para boas práticas do `python` (`PEP8`) e o `number` é verificado se é maior ou menor que a média, incluindo assim no respectivo vetor.

Após isso, mostramos todos os nossos resultados de uma maneira clara, apesar do `print()` ter ficado um pouco grande com várias informações.

```
print('\n* A soma dos valores do vetor {} totaliza o valor de {}!\n* A média dos valores é: {}\n* Temos {} números abaixo da média: {}\n* E temos {} números acima da média: {}'.format(numbers, sum_numbers, average, len(below_average_numbers), below_average_numbers, len(above_average_numbers), above_average_numbers))
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara ajudou muito, tenho que fazer uma lista de 16 exercícios, e tenho que aprender python praticamente sozinho! Vlw mesmo!

Comment: Que bom @UberlanTorres, qualquer dúvida que tenha sobre este mesmo fluxo, basta realizar um comentário nesta resposta que no momento que ver a notificação venho te auxiliar. Caso esta resposta resolveu o problema ou foi útil para encontrar a solução, poderá aceita-la clicando no v(zinho) que está ao lado da pergunta. Para que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema sejam ajudadas por uma resposta validada.